# Play! - Java - not detecting additional class and package

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I using play 2.04 Java. I've create an additional package named **util** and a class named **Node.java** as can be seen below:-

[image: Project tree]

I have a view in the views.html.* package called **test.scala.html** that takes **Node** as a parameter as in the following:-

```
@(rootNode: Node[Category]

@rootNode
```

When the view is rendered I get the error:-

[image: View error]

[Anatomy of a play 2.0 application](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/Anatomy) states that it's not a problem adding additional packages and classes.

Is there something in the configuration of play that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only classes from `controllers` and `models` packages are imported to views automatically, so, you need to use the full qualified name of your class, ie `util.Node` instead of `Node`:

```
@(rootNode: util.Node[Category]

@rootNode
```